# Spline plugin doesn't work

Tags: qgis-plugins, spline

I have Spline plugin installed. It is activated. When I try to draw a curved line it doesn't change into a curve. The lines remain the way I have drawn them. I am using QGIS 2.10.1 with Windows 8 or 7.

I also get this Warning, but I don't understand what does it mean and how to deal with it:

```
2015-10-20T16:22:15 1
warning:C:/Users/katy/.qgis2/python/plugins\spline\spline.py:116: DeprecationWarning: QgsMapCanvas.mapRenderer() is deprecated
if self.canvas.mapRenderer().hasCrsTransformEnabled() and layer.crs() != self.canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs():
traceback:  File "C:/Users/katy/.qgis2/python/plugins\spline\spline.py", line 96, in canvasPressEvent
                self.createFeature()
```

Please. Help me with Spline or suggest another way to digitize curved lines.